# Remove Make goal passed from commandline

Tags: makefile

Before beheading me for abusing make, is it possible to remove a goal passed on the command line?

Something like `MAKECMDGOALS := $(wordlist 1,2,$(MAKECMDGOALS))` ?

I've tried this but it still goes on and makes the other rules anyway...

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Quick-Reference.html):

> MAKECMDGOALS
>
> The targets given to make on the command line. **Setting this variable has no effect on the operation of make.**

(Emphasis added.)